# web-mode comment function doesn't work well in php codes

Tags: web-mode

In web-mode, when it comes to HTML file, press M-; will comment the selected region very well. But in PHP file, it does not work correctly, the following is the screenshot:[image]

Any more config work should be done?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe a bug report or enhancement request to the web-mode maintainer is in order.

Comment: Did a stab myself, lucky me it works. Changed line 751 in web-mode.el like this:    (defvar web-mode-comment-formats
  '(("java"       . "/*")
    ("javascript" . "/*")
    ("php"        . "//");Jasondf changed here, used to be /*
    ))     Now M-; works in PHP file and php block in HTML file. Although I don't know if there is any side effects.

Comment: Great. Please consider sending your fix to the web-mode maintainer, for consideration to be applied to the code.

Comment: Well, that's a brutal stab to the source file, not sure he will like that. Already added my comment to the issue in github anyway...

Comment: @Drew there is a better solution in [github issue link](https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/589)